# Should we pass a variable that can be acquired in O(1) into nested functions, or recall that function within every nested function?

Tags: performance, function, parameters, coding-style, standards

The example below explains the question best. Which is standard: (A) or (B)?

**A) Passing Variable in Each Nested Function:**

```py
def bar(X, y, n_rows, n_cols):
    # Do stuff....
    return stuff

def foo(X, y, n_rows, n_cols):
    stuff = bar(X, y, n_rows, n_cols)
    # Do stuff...
    return stuff
```

**B) Recalling O(1) Function within each Nested Function:**

```py
def bar(X, y):
    n_rows = get_number_of_rows(X)  # X.shape[0]
    n_cols = get_number_of_cols(X)  # X.shape[1]
    # Do stuff....
    return stuff

def foo(X, y):
    n_rows = get_number_of_rows(X)  # X.shape[0]
    n_cols = get_number_of_cols(X)  # X.shape[1]
    stuff = bar(X, y)
    # Do stuff...
    return stuff
```

It seems kind of verbose to pass the number of rows and columns into nested functions, but on the other hand it seems inefficient to keep setting variables. I am not even too sure if the number of rows and columns can be acquired in constant time O(1). I wrote this in Python (using R in reality), but my goal was to frame this question generically enough that it could be applied to any language.

**Helpful Links:**
[Are there guidelines on how many parameters a function should accept?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145055/are-there-guidelines-on-how-many-parameters-a-function-should-accept) (Suggests making this an object to avoid multiple parameters)

**Questions:**

1. Which is better for readability?
2. Which is better for performance?
3. Should we code in a way that this situation never arrises?
4. Could the answer for (1) and (2) be different for different languages?

P.S. Need a little help with the naming of this question – less verbose more generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that

1. `B` is preferred because it avoids some problems with changing the number or names of parameters. Option `A` has a code smell [data clumps](https://refactoring.guru/smells/data-clumps), and `B` is his solution called [preserve whole object](https://refactoring.guru/preserve-whole-object).

   Also both approaches have a [`trump data`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tramp_data) smell. Which can be solved by making the OO re-design and making the passed variables members of the class. Or the introduction of a global or context variable (but this is *quite rare*)
2. If there are no unwanted side effects or copying large objects by value, then performance can be neglected. And I would advise you to adhere to the following rule when developing: [**Don't do premature optimization.**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)
3. The word "never" does not apply in software design. It all depends on the context.
4. I think so, and not only for different languages, but also on the problem being solved within the framework of one language, the tools used, libraries, frameworks, etc.

Comment: One more aspect: Version A is error-prone. A `foo()` or `bar()` caller has to redundantly pass the dimensions of the array into the function. There's no use case for passing into `n_rows` and `n_cols` anything that isn't already known via `X`, moreover, it will probably give nonsense results.